# How to show a "saved" message after every ajax request in text area

Tags: jquery, autosave

Hi I have text area with ajax request to save the text in drafts. when i navigate to form page and start writing text in textarea , it only first time shows the message of "saved as draft " after that it doesnt give any message in a div that i set.So i want to display this message after completion of my every ajax request . Here is my code , please suggest.

```
$(function() {
    autoSaveEntry()
});
function autoSaveEntry() {
  if($('#txtarea').val().length>0){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/account/drafts/"+$('#dreft_id').val(),
        dataType: "script",
        async: "true",
        type: "PUT",
        data: {
                body:$('#txtarea').val()
              },
        success: function() {

            $('#message').append('Saved as draft');

            setTimeout(function () {

                $('#message').fadeOut(function(){

                    $(this).remove();

                });

            }, 2000);

        }
    });
  }
  setTimeout(autoSaveEntry, 5000)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){autoSaveEntry()}, 5000);
```

Or even better move this in the in:

$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){autoSaveEntry()}, 5000);
});

Answer (score 0):

That is because you removed the message div from the DOM.
Do not append the div, just add it in the html and set its style to display:none

HTML

```
<div style = 'display:none' id = 'message'></div>
```

AND

replace:

```
 $('#message').fadeOut(function(){
          $(this).remove();
});
```

By:

```
$('#message').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing message div so that second time script doesn't get where to put 'Saved as draft' this message.

So that only do blank #message div by replacing $(this).remove(); by  $(this).html('');

And final code is below. It will work for you.

```
  $(function() {
      autoSaveEntry()
   });
  function autoSaveEntry() {
    if($('#txtarea').val().length>0){
      $.ajax({
          url: "/account/drafts/"+$('#dreft_id').val(),
        dataType: "script",
        async: "true",
        type: "PUT",
        data: {
                body:$('#txtarea').val()
              },
        success: function() {

            $('#message').append('Saved as draft');

            setTimeout(function () {

                $('#message').fadeOut(function(){

                    $(this).html('');

                });

            }, 2000);

        }
    });
  }
  setTimeout(autoSaveEntry, 5000)

}
```

Enjoy...!!